# Using a complete date field in a oracle sql where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I'm trying to create a where clause that can return a datetime interval with the table following, being more specific, i'm using this query:

```
select *
from tb_alarms c
where to_char(c.e3timestamp, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') >= '13/09/2017 16:00'
and   to_char(c.e3timestamp, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') <= '14/09/2017 07:05'
```

However, this query returns rows with the e3timestamp field with values starting at 14/06/2011 07:49:29 and ending with 14/09/2017 07:04:30.

Why does it return a date with 2011 year? Is it because it's comparing a char and not a date type?

Can you guys help me or indicate sources where I can learn how to do a correct where clause with a complete datetime interval?

Thank you!

OBS: e3timestamp is a field with Date type in the tb_alarms table.

Comment: why can't you compare it the other way ? `where c.e3timestamp > = to_date('13/09/2017 16:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use to_date and not to_char, also avoid using functions on your columns because this prevent the use of the index:

```
select *
from tb_alarms c
where c.e3timestamp between to_date('13/09/2017 16:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
and   to_date('14/09/2017 07:05','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi');
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why does it return a date with 2011 year? Is it because it's comparing a char and not a date type?

Yes, `'13/09/2017 16:00'` is a String literal not a Date literal - the query will compare the left- and right-hand sides of the filter condition as strings and not as dates.

So these are both true:

```
'13/09/2017 16:00' <= '14/09/0001 00:00'
'14/09/0001 00:00' <= '14/09/2017 07:05'
```

You want to use a timestamp literal:

```
select *
from tb_alarms c
where c.e3timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2017-09-13 16:00:00'
                        AND TIMESTAMP '2017-09-14 07:05:00'
```

or use `TO_DATE` on your string literals instead of using `TO_CHAR` on you date/timestamp column:

```
select *
from tb_alarms c
where c.e3timestamp >= TO_DATE( '13/09/2017 16:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI' )
AND   c.e3timestamp <= TO_DATE( '14/09/2017 07:05', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI' )
```

Comment: Well explained.